# how to disable nose test's coverage report

Tags: python, django, testing, nose

Hopefully a simple python/django `nose` test question, though I can't find the answer in `nose`'s documentation.

How do I stop the coverage report showing up after I run the tests with `./manage.py test`?

I have a huge problem with the coverage report forcing me to scroll back a few dozen lines to get the traceback of my failing test, it really interrupts my workflow! I like using `nose`, but if I can't figure out how to get rid of this I'll have to go back to vanilla django tests.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Here's what I have to scroll back through to get to the traceback:

```
./manage.py test
[...]
======================================================================
FAIL: testFreightAveragesContainer ([...].tests.test_average_container.AveragesContainerTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/tests/test_average_container.py", line 32, in testAveragesContainer
    121
AssertionError: 12 != 121

Name                                                    Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc.advertising                                             0      0   100%   
abc.advertising.management                                  0      0   100%   
abc.advertising.models                                     73     73     0%   1-91
abc.client                                                  0      0   100%   
abc.client.admin                                          200    200     0%   1-430
abc.client.forms                                           57     57     0%   1-99
abc.client.management                                       0      0   100%   
abc.client.models                                         434    434     0%   1-1007
abc.client.translations                                    30     30     0%   1-33
abc.client.views                                           18     18     0%   1-24
abc.cms                                                     0      0   100%   
abc.cms.management                                          0      0   100%   
abc.cms.models                                            235    235     0%   1-416
abc.cms.translations                                       18     18     0%   1-21
abc.commodity                                               0      0   100%   
abc.commodity.admin                                        51     51     0%   1-107
abc.commodity.forms                                        12      0   100%   
abc.commodity.models                                      343    343     0%   1-669
abc.commodity.search_indexes                               10      1    90%   13
abc.commodity.tests                                         5      3    40%   3-6
abc.commodity.tests.test_average_container                 14      1    93%   37
abc.commodity.tests.test_lead_time_analyser                70      0   100%   
abc.commodity.tests.test_price_analysers                    6      2    67%   10, 15
abc.commodity.translations                                 38     38     0%   1-40
abc.commodity.urls                                         11      0   100%   
abc.commodity.views                                       452    359    21%   22-25, 29-32, 74, 83-96, 101-142, 151-159, 166-172, 179-192, 198-250, 260-264, 287-288, 300-314, 321-378, 385-433, 441-502, 509-557, 563-567, 574-581, 587-662, 668-672, 679-686, 694-722, 730-754, 761-843, 850-854, 861-871, 878-904, 951-952, 962-978, 990-1010
abc.data_submission                                         0      0   100%   
abc.data_submission.iron_ore_submission_normalisation     187    187     0%   1-481
abc.data_submission.managers                               27     27     0%   1-71
abc.data_submission.models                                635    635     0%   1-1222
abc.invoicing                                               0      0   100%   
abc.invoicing.models                                      261    261     0%   1-440
abc.invoicing.translations                                 25     25     0%   1-26
abc.localisation                                            0      0   100%   
abc.localisation.management                                 0      0   100%   
abc.localisation.models                                   167    167     0%   1-528
abc.localisation.translation                                0      0   100%   
abc.localisation.translation.models                       144    144     0%   1-318
abc.localisation.translations                              22     22     0%   1-24
abc.mailing                                                 0      0   100%   
abc.mailing.admin                                         110    110     0%   1-165
abc.mailing.forms                                          33     33     0%   1-44
abc.mailing.management                                      0      0   100%   
abc.mailing.models                                        337    337     0%   1-706
abc.mailing.translations                                   15     15     0%   1-16
abc.marketing                                               0      0   100%   
abc.marketing.models                                        0      0   100%   
abc.product                                                 0      0   100%   
abc.product.models                                          0      0   100%   
abc.staff                                                   0      0   100%   
abc.staff.models                                           80     80     0%   1-154
.staff.translations                                      4      4     0%   1-5
abc.utils                                                   0      0   100%   
abc.utils.base                                              9      9     0%   1-19
abc.utils.base.models                                     187    187     0%   1-435
abc.utils.custom_ui                                         0      0   100%   
abc.utils.custom_ui.advanced_filter                       175    175     0%   1-241
abc.utils.custom_ui.models                                  3      3     0%   1-5
abc.utils.date                                             41     41     0%   1-73
abc.utils.db                                                0      0   100%   
abc.utils.db.routers                                       21     19    10%   1-7, 10, 13-32
abc.utils.format                                           33     33     0%   1-60
abc.utils.models                                           10     10     0%   1-30
abc.utils.navigation                                       10     10     0%   2-19
abc.utils.views                                            23     23     0%   1-42
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                    4636   4420     5%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 9 tests in 0.059s

FAILED (failures=1)
./manage.py test commodity --failfast  13.59s user 0.17s system 97% cpu 14.099 total
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which versions of Django and nose are you using? As far as I'm aware, this is not the default behaviour of Django's test running and it's definitely not default for nose.

The relevant option to give to nose to toggle use of the [coverage plugin](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html) is "--with-coverage".

I'm not sure you managed to turn coverage on by accident, you should look in settings.py 
for variables like COVERAGE_MODULES and TEST_RUNNER and see what they're set to.

Comment: A member of my team switch on --with-coverage. Thanks!

Comment: you can uninstall coverage reports with: pip uninstall coverage

Answer (score 4):

You can:

```
pip install nose-cov
```

Which has more control over reporting options and will not report to console unless you ask it to. Then change `--with-coverage` to `--with-cov`:

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
 '--with-cov',
 '--cov-report', 'html',
]
```

This will only export to html.

Same question here:

[Disabling nose coverage report to STDOUT when HTML report is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725193/disabling-nose-coverage-report-to-stdout-when-html-report-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Django manage.py script, but I guess that you can look into the "test" task and see hot it calls nose. I guess that you would like to only run the tests, without the coverage.
Nose documentation is here http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.3/usage.html