# Disabling nose coverage report to STDOUT when HTML report is enabled?

Tags: python, nose, nosetests, coverage.py

I'm using [nose](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose) (via [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose)) with the [coverage plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/cover.html) to check test coverage of my Django project.

I've configured nose to generate an HTML coverage report on every test run:

```
NOSE_ARGS = [                                                                   
    '--with-coverage',                                                            
    '--cover-package=foot',                                                       
    '--cover-html',                                                               
    '--cover-html-dir=cover',
]
```

Now, I want to disable the plain-text coverage report that gets shown after every test run; the HTML is much more functional, and the long badly-formatted table makes it hard to see actual test output. Neither `nosetests` nor `coverage` seems to have such an option, or perhaps I just can't find one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Taken from [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065455/how-to-disable-nose-tests-coverage-report?lq=1))

You can install `nose-cov`:

```
pip install nose-cov
```

which has more control over reporting options. Then, change `--with-coverage` to `--with-cover`, *e.g.*

```
NOSE_ARGS = [
 '--with-cov',
 '--cov-report', 'html',
]
```

which will export to HTML but suppress console output.

Comment: Thanks! The question isn't *exactly* the same (that user had `--with-coverage` on by mistake), but `nose-cov` is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A quick-and-dirty fix is to comment out the line that generates the unformatted coverage report in `nose/plugins/cover.py`:

```
def report(self, stream):
    ....
    log.debug("Coverage report will cover modules: %s", modules)
    #self.coverInstance.report(modules, file=stream)
```